# Copy tensor using K.tile()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, copy, tensor, replicate

I have tensor `(None, 196)` and after reshaping, it becomes `(None, 14, 14)`.
And now, I want to copy it to channel axis, so that the shape should be `(None, 14, 14, 512)`. Lastly, I want to copy to timestep axis, so it becomes `(None, 10, 14, 14, 512)`. I accomplish those steps using this snippet code:

```
def replicate(tensor, input_target):
  batch_size = K.shape(tensor)[0]
  nf, h, w, c = input_target
  x = K.reshape(tensor, [batch_size, 1, h, w, 1])

  # Replicate to channel dimension
  x = K.tile(x, [batch_size, 1, 1, 1, c])

  # Replicate to timesteps dimension
  x = K.tile(x, [batch_size, nf, 1, 1, 1])

  return x

x = ...
x = Lambda(replicate, arguments={'input_target':input_shape})(x)
another_x = Input(shape=input_shape) # shape (10, 14, 14, 512)

x = layers.multiply([x, another_x])
x = ...
```

I plot the model and the output shape is just like I want it to be. But, the problem arises in model training. I set the batch size to 2. This the the error message:

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [8,10,14,14,512] vs. [2,10,14,14,512]
         [[{{node multiply_1/mul}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training/Adam/gradients/multiply_1/mul_grad/Sum"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Lambda_2/Tile_1, _arg_another_x_0_0/_189)]]
         [[{{node metrics/top_k_categorical_accuracy/Mean_1/_265}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_6346_metrics/top_k_categorical_accuracy/Mean_1", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]`

Looks like, `K.tile()` increases the batch size from 2 to 8. When I set the batch size to 10, it becomes 1000.

So, my question is how to achieve the result as I want? Is it good way to use `tile()`? Or, should I use `repeat_elements()`? Thanks!

I am using Tensorflow 1.12.0 and Keras 2.2.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, try to avoid bringing batch size to the transformations happening in the `Lambda` layer.

When you use `tile` operation, you only set **only** the dimension that needs to change (for example you had `batch_size` value in your tile operation which is wrong). Also I am using `tf.tile` instead of `K.tile` (TF 1.12 doesn't have tile in the Keras backend it seems).

```
def replicate(tensor, input_target):

  _, nf, h, w, c = input_target
  x = K.reshape(tensor, [-1, 1, h, w, 1])

  # Replicate to channel dimension
  # You can combine below lines to tf.tile(x, [1, nf, 1, 1, c]) as well
  x = tf.tile(x, [1, 1, 1, 1, c])
  # Replicate to timesteps dimension
  x = tf.tile(x, [1, nf, 1, 1, 1])


  return x
```

### Simple example

```
input_shape= [None, 10, 14, 14, 512]
x = Input(shape=(196,))
x = Lambda(replicate, arguments={'input_target':input_shape})(x)
print(x.shape)
```

Which gives

```
>>> (?, 10, 14, 14, 512)
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I am using `K.tile` actually. By the way, which one is good to copy the tensor for my case: `tile()` or `repeat_elements()` ?

Comment: I don't think it matters that much for your case because you are going from 1-> some number `n`, for which both will produce the same results. But if you are going from m -> n, then you will get different outputs depending on which function you used.